# Standard .NET side enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums, direction

I often use enums like

```
public enum Side { Left, Top, Right, Bottom };
```

or

```
public enum Direction { Left, Up, Right, Down };
```

Every time I describe the enum again. Is there a standard enum of this kind in .NET?

Comment: Do you mean, every time you write a new app? Maybe you can start your own framework for repeating tasks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not quite the same, but I know of the `System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles` enumeration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.anchorstyles.aspx

Otherwise, I'd say not - add it to your own common library. You also have to consider the cost of taking dependencies (even on .NET Framework stuff), because of things like portability. I wouldn't take one on WinForms unless you are already depending on WinForms.

Comment: Yeah but it's called AnchorStyles and even the values are quite the same, the enum is **not semantically the same**. Be carefull (imagine Microsoft adding a new value to AnchorStyles in the future).

Comment: @YvesM. The values differ from what was stated in the question, but to your point they are very close.

Answer (score 2):

Old and answered, but there is a `ArrowDirection` enum. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.arrowdirection(v=vs.110).aspx.  Unfortunately, it is in System.Windows.Forms.